# Cannot access to localhost

Tags: google-cloud-platform, localhost, google-kubernetes-engine

I deployed an application on Google Cloud (GKE). In order to access its UI, I did port-forwarding(port 9090). When I use Cloud Shell web preview I can access the UI. However, when I tried to open localhost:9090 in my browser, I cannot access. Do you know why I cannot access from my browser, is it normal?
Thank you!

Comment: It's unclear from your question but presumably you're port-forwarding from with Cloud Shell i.e. Cloud Shell is where you're running `kubectl port-forward`. Port forwarding only applies to the host on which the command is run unless you have a chain of port-forwarding commands. If you want to access the UI from your local host, then you will need to run the `kubectl port-forward` on your local host too.

Comment: Yes, I am running port-forward on Google Shell. I understand what you mean. But also a bit confused. So how can I can run kubectl port-forward command on my local host for the application that I deployed cloud? Should I install Google Cloud CLI on my local machine?

Comment: I assumed (!) that you're using `kubectl port-forward` on Cloud Shell. If that's correct, then you need to install  install `kubectl` on your local machine to run it there. Because of the way that GKE authenticates, it may also be prudent to install [`gcloud`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) on your local machine. You can then use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` to create a local Kubernete (GKE) config file on your local machine that is then used by `kubectl` commands.

Comment: Yes, I was using the command on Google Shell. And as you said I installed it on my local computer, and I can access the port from my localhost. Actually, installing gcloud on my local machine also solve other problems that I was facing, I assume it was caused by web preview. Thank you a lot!

Comment: Great! You're welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Answered provided in the comments by a community member.

**Do you know why I cannot access from my browser, is it normal?**

Cloud Shell is where you're running `kubectl port-forward`. Port forwarding only applies to the host on which the command is run unless you have a chain of port-forwarding commands. If you want to access the UI from your local host, then you will need to run the `kubectl port-forward` on your local host too.

**So how can I can run kubectl port-forward command on my local host for the application that I deployed cloud? Should I install Google Cloud CLI on my local machine?**

I assumed (!) that you're using `kubectl port-forward` on Cloud Shell. If that's correct, then you need to install `kubectl` on your local machine to run it there. Because of the way that GKE authenticates, it may also be prudent to install `gcloud` on your local machine. You can then use `gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...` to create a local Kubernete (GKE) config file on your local machine that is then used by `kubectl` commands.